# yaml.load() without loader is deprecated, --backend-config

Tags: bash, yaml, backend

I'm running a python script on PythonAnywhere and I'm accessing an API through an yaml config file. My bash command line is:

```
pylivetrader run-f bb.py --backend-config config.yaml
```

However this method calls the `yaml.load` function without specifying any arguments and this method is deprecated.

```
YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe.
```

I wonder how can I run this command on the bash in a safe way?

I appreciate the help guys!

Regards

Comment: You can make the warning go away with `PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore::yaml.YAMLLoadWarning`. Other than that, the program itself should be fixed. Look here https://github.com/alpacahq/pylivetrader if it was already fixed, or create an issue

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I'll create a new issue